# Finding the MLE when given the mean and sd

Tags: r, self-study, maximum-likelihood, mean, standard-deviation

I have been given some data about people on an island:

$X_A \sim N (1.8, 0.2)$

$X_B \sim N (1.9, 0.3)$

Where $X_A$ is the height of people from island $A$, with a mean height of 1.8 and SD of 0.2 and $X_B$ is the height of people from island $B$ with a mean height of 1.9 and SD of 0.3 (all units meters).

We are asked to find how tall someone needs to be so we can be reasonably sure that they come from island $B$.

Using a likelihood function where $X$ is fixed, I've come up with the following:

RCode:

```
f <- function(x){dnorm(x,mean=1.9,sd=0.3)}
x <- seq(from=1.8,to=2.2,len=100)
plot(x,sapply(x,f))
grid();
```

[image]

Given two significant figures of support, I believe the answer is between 1.8m to 2m as I find it closest to the MLE.

Comment: It is not possible to be *certain* someone comes from island B.

Comment: Cheers Glen, edited and noted.

Comment: It would also be advisable to explain the algorithm you're trying to implement in code; firstly that removes confusion between whether what you're trying to do is right from whether you correctly implemented it in R, and secondly questions about correctness of code are usually [off topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: "Reasonably sure" is still ambiguous. You're a statistician! Create a decision rule and find its false positive error rate! MLEs have nothing to do with anything here. You have the probability model, so its a probability question, no estimation needed.